# Fragment implements show error "must either be declared abstarct or implement abstarct method"

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment named `FragmentThree` which implements `View.OnTouchListener` and it shows this show error:

> Class 'FragmentThree' must either be declared abstarct or implement abstarct method

```
package com.chrisrisner.fragmentsample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link FragmentThree.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link FragmentThree#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class FragmentThree extends Fragment implements View.OnTouchListener{
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentThree.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FragmentThree newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentThree fragment = new FragmentThree();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public FragmentThree() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_three, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

But I have another project which have a fragment `RegistrationFragment` like this with no error:

```
public class RegistrationFragment extends Fragment 
     implements View.OnTouchListener, EditText.OnEditorActionListener, APIResponse {
```

Why do I have this error on `FragmentThree`?

Comment: Another extra note. Please, for your own sake and for the sake of other people with whom you are going to work with: do give meaningful names to your classes, methods, and variables. For example, `private String mParam1;` does not give me a single clue what that variable is responsible for!

Answer (score 0):

Just add this method to your class:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return false;
}
```

In fact, the question is barely understandable, make sure to post at least some code next time, for us to better understand what's the issue

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have added the code with question. please have a look.

Comment: @Harunduet I see the code. What is happening is that you have specified that your class is going to implement `View.OnTouchListener` interface, which required you to implement `onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)` method, without actually implementing that method. Thus, just add my piece of code to your class and you should be fire

Comment: Thanks a lot... Problem solved after adding your suggested method.